# Funnel shift - what is it?

Tags: cuda, intrinsics, ptx

When reading through CUDA 5.0 Programming Guide I stumbled on a feature called "Funnel shift" which is present in 3.5 compute-capable device, but not 3.0. It contains an annotation "see reference manual", but when I search for the "funnel shift" term in the manual, I don't find anything.

I tried googling for it, but only found a mention on http://www.cudahandbook.com, in the chapter 8:

> 8.2.3 Funnel Shift (SM 3.5)
>
> GK110 added a 64-bit “funnel shift” instruction that may be accessed with the following intrinsics:
>
> __funnelshift_lc(): returns most significant 32 bits of a left funnel shift.
>
> __funnelshift_rc(): returns least significant 32 bits of a right funnel shift.
>
> These intrinsics are implemented as inline device
>   functions (using inline PTX assembler) in sm_35_intrinsics.h.

...but it still does not explain what the "left funnel shift" or "right funnel shift" is.

So, what is it and where does one need it?

Comment: Funnel shifting is where two input words are concatenated and then shifted, and a word size output extracted from the result of the concatenate/shift.

Comment: Is it something different than __shfl_up(value, index) ?

Comment: As talonmies says, a funnel shifter extracts any contiguous n-bit group of bits from the concatenation of two n-bit words. Note that a funnel shifter provides for efficient implementation of rotates, by making both inputs the same n-bit word. Use of the term "funnel" alludes to the fact that the input is wider than the output.

Comment: Ah, this is good feedback on the CUDA handbook.  I need to add a bit of clarifying language there, it seems :-)

Comment: @ahmad, yes, it is different than __shfl_up().  The shuffle instructions enable data interchange between threads within a warp.

Comment: talonmies, njuffa, Archaea, want to write an answer?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think I understand what it does, but some nice answer (maybe with a nice example for clarity) would be great! For me and perhaps for others who might stumble on it. Also, nice to meet the handbook's author here. Didn't expect that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of CUDA, two 32-bit registers are concatenated together into a 64-bit value; that value is shifted left or right; and the most significant (for a left shift) or least significant (for right shift) 32 bits are returned.

The intrinsics from `sm_35_intrinsics.h` are as follows:

```
unsigned int __funnelshift_lc(unsigned int lo, unsigned int hi, unsigned int shift);
unsigned int __funnelshift_rc(unsigned int lo, unsigned int hi, unsigned int shift);
```

According to Andy Glew (dead link removed), applications for funnel shift include fast misaligned memcpy; and as njuffa mentions in the comments above, it can be used to implement rotate if the two input words are the same.

Comment: So it sounds like in simple terms it's a 64-bit shift w/ 32-bit operands and results? Presumably because the registers are all 32-bit.

Comment: Yes, in fact on machines with 64-bit registers, a funnel shift would let you do 128-bit shifts on register pairs.

Comment: Note: the link appears to be down.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware: The link is dead.

Comment: I wrote Andy a while ago and he said he would fix the link, but no such luck. I have lightly edited the answer to remove the link.